# I'm struggling to solve a percentage computation

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm ripping my hair out on the following so I'm kindly asking for help here.

I have an array of durations in minutes whose total is one day (1440 min.)
I have another array with a value which represent a protection level : 0 to 5.

```
var levels = new int[3];            
levels[0] = 0;
levels[1] = 5;
levels[2] = 0;

var minutes = new int[3];   
minutes[0] = 658; // 10 hours and 58 minutes
minutes[1] = 1; // 1 minute
minutes[2] = 781; // 13 hours and 1 minutes
```

In plain English we should read:
Level 0 duration is 10 hours and 58 minutes, then Level 1 duration is 1 minute and finally we're back to level 0 for 13 hours and 1 minute. End of the day ;)

Of couse this is a simple example, this could be more richer than that, but I hope this helps understand the problem I'm trying to solve which is exposed below.

I need to compute an average of protection level for each hour of the day (from 0 to 23)\

The final result set would be an array of tuples with 6 items

```
var finalResult = new (int level0percent, int level1percent, int level2percent, int level3percent, int level4percent, int level5percent)[24];
```

With the data in this example that would mean:

- 100% for level 0 for Hours from 0 to 9
- 96% for level 0 for Hour 10

A this point we have 2 minutes left (4%) to be given to Hour 10.

- We consume 2% (1 minute) for level 5

Still 2% (1 minute) to consume on the next level, which is 0 for now.

- We add 2% (1 minute) to level 0

Then the remaining is now 13 hours for level 0 at index 11 to 23.

The tricky part for me is to process, in this case, the hour at index 10. May be I should restructure the data in a form that would be simplier to process, but I can't figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

PS : If Linq could be of any help, please do not hesitate to use it.

---

EDIT : Fixed the minutes array.

EDIT 2 : This what I've tried so far...

A level class to hold an intermediary result set:

```
public class Levels
{
    public int level0 { get; set; }


    public int level1 { get; set; }


    public int level2 { get; set; }


    public int level3 { get; set; }


    public int level4 { get; set; }


    public int level5 { get; set; }

}
```

The processing code so far... May not compile and/or work:

```
// Construct the final result to be sent back to the client
var averagesOn24HoursByHourNew = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(i => new Levels()).ToArray();

// This index will allow us to advance each hour of the day (from 0 to 23)
int lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew = 0;

// Used to gather the remaining minutes for incomplete hours
int lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour = 0;

for (var indexLevel = 0; indexLevel < levels.Count; indexLevel++)
{
    if (levels[indexLevel] == 0)
    {
        int durationInMinutes = (int)minutes[indexLevel];

        var nbMinutesLeft = durationInMinutes % 60;
        var nbHoursAtOneHundred = durationInMinutes / 60;
        if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0)
        {
            averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew].level0 += lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour * 100 / 60;
            nbMinutesLeft -= lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour;
            lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour = 0;
        }

        int index = 0;
        for (index = lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index < nbHoursAtOneHundred + lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index++)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debug.Assert(index <= 23);
#endif

            averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level0 += 100;


            datiCountForOneHour[index] += 1;
        }
#if DEBUG
        // When th whole day is processed the index will be 24
        Debug.Assert(index < 25);
#endif
        if (nbMinutesLeft != 0)
        {
            averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level0 += nbMinutesLeft * 100 / 60;
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0 && lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour > nbMinutesLeft)
            {
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour -= nbMinutesLeft;
            }
            else
            {
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour = 60 - nbMinutesLeft;
            }
        }

        lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew = index;
    }
    else if (levels[indexLevel] == 1)
    {
        int durationInMinutes = (int)minutes[indexLevel];

        // A duration of zero means less than one minute
        // set it to one minute
        if (durationInMinutes == 0)
        {
            durationInMinutes = 1;
        }
        else if (durationInMinutes == 1439)
        {
            // FIXME Add Missing minute if needed
            durationInMinutes = 1440;
        }

        var nbMinutesLeft = durationInMinutes % 60;

        var nbHoursAtOneHundred = durationInMinutes / 60;
        int index = 0;
        for (index = lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index < nbHoursAtOneHundred + lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index++)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debug.Assert(index <= 23);
#endif
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0)
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level1 += lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour * 100 / 60;
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level1 += 100;
            }

            datiCountForOneHour[index] += 1;
        }
#if DEBUG
        // When th whole day is processed the index will be 24
        Debug.Assert(index < 25);
#endif
        if (nbMinutesLeft != 0)
        {
            averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level1 += nbMinutesLeft * 100 / 60;
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0 && lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour > nbMinutesLeft)
            {
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour -= nbMinutesLeft;
            }
        }

        lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew = index;
    }
    else if (levels[indexLevel] == 2)
    {
        int durationInMinutes = (int)minutes[indexLevel];

        // A duration of zero means less than one minute
        // set it to one minute
        if (durationInMinutes == 0)
        {
            durationInMinutes = 1;
        }
        else if (durationInMinutes == 1439)
        {
            // FIXME Add Missing minute if needed
            durationInMinutes = 1440;
        }

        var nbMinutesLeft = durationInMinutes % 60;

        var nbHoursAtOneHundred = durationInMinutes / 60;
        int index = 0;
        for (index = lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index < nbHoursAtOneHundred + lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index++)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debug.Assert(index <= 23);
#endif
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0)
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level2 += lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour * 100 / 60;
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level2 += 100;
            }

            datiCountForOneHour[index] += 1;
        }
#if DEBUG
        // When th whole day is processed the index will be 24
        Debug.Assert(index < 25);
#endif
        if (nbMinutesLeft != 0)
        {
            averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level2 += nbMinutesLeft * 100 / 60;
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0 && lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour > nbMinutesLeft)
            {
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour -= nbMinutesLeft;
            }
        }

        lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew = index;
    }
    else if (levels[indexLevel] == 3)
    {
        int durationInMinutes = (int)minutes[indexLevel];

        // A duration of zero means less than one minute
        // set it to one minute
        if (durationInMinutes == 0)
        {
            durationInMinutes = 1;
        }
        else if (durationInMinutes == 1439)
        {
            // FIXME Add Missing minute if needed
            durationInMinutes = 1440;
        }

        var nbMinutesLeft = durationInMinutes % 60;

        var nbHoursAtOneHundred = durationInMinutes / 60;
        int index = 0;
        for (index = lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index < nbHoursAtOneHundred + lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index++)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debug.Assert(index <= 23);
#endif
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0)
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level3 += lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour * 100 / 60;
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level3 += 100;
            }

            datiCountForOneHour[index] += 1;
        }
#if DEBUG
        // When th whole day is processed the index will be 24
        Debug.Assert(index < 25);
#endif
        if (nbMinutesLeft != 0)
        {
            averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level3 += nbMinutesLeft * 100 / 60;
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0 && lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour > nbMinutesLeft)
            {
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour -= nbMinutesLeft;
            }
        }

        lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew = index;
    }
    else if (levels[indexLevel] == 4)
    {
        int durationInMinutes = (int)minutes[indexLevel];

        // A duration of zero means less than one minute
        // set it to one minute
        if (durationInMinutes == 0)
        {
            durationInMinutes = 1;
        }
        else if (durationInMinutes == 1439)
        {
            // FIXME Add Missing minute if needed
            durationInMinutes = 1440;
        }

        var nbMinutesLeft = durationInMinutes % 60;

        var nbHoursAtOneHundred = durationInMinutes / 60;
        int index = 0;
        for (index = lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index < nbHoursAtOneHundred + lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index++)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debug.Assert(index <= 23);
#endif
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0)
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level4 += lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour * 100 / 60;
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level4 += 100;
            }

            datiCountForOneHour[index] += 1;
        }
#if DEBUG
        // When th whole day is processed the index will be 24
        Debug.Assert(index < 25);
#endif
        if (nbMinutesLeft != 0)
        {
            averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level4 += nbMinutesLeft * 100 / 60;
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0 && lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour > nbMinutesLeft)
            {
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour -= nbMinutesLeft;
            }
        }

        lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew = index;
    }
    else if (levels[indexLevel] == 5)
    {
        int durationInMinutes = (int)minutes[indexLevel];

        // A duration of zero means less than one minute
        // set it to one minute
        if (durationInMinutes == 0)
        {
            durationInMinutes = 1;
        }
        else if (durationInMinutes == 1439)
        {
            // FIXME Add Missing minute if needed
            durationInMinutes = 1440;
        }

        var nbMinutesLeft = durationInMinutes % 60;

        var nbHoursAtOneHundred = durationInMinutes / 60;
        int index = 0;
        for (index = lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index < nbHoursAtOneHundred + lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew; index++)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debug.Assert(index <= 23);
#endif
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0)
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level5 += lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour * 100 / 60;
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level5 += 100;
            }

            datiCountForOneHour[index] += 1;
        }
#if DEBUG
        // When th whole day is processed the index will be 24
        Debug.Assert(index < 25);
#endif
        if (nbMinutesLeft != 0)
        {
            averagesOn24HoursByHourNew[index].level5 += nbMinutesLeft * 100 / 60;
            if (lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour != 0 && lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour > nbMinutesLeft)
            {
                lastMinuteLeftOnLastHour -= nbMinutesLeft;
            }
        }

        lastIndexOnAveragesOn24HoursByHourNew = index;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid protection level found in stats");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"for each hour of the day"* - start by breaking your durations into the hours into which they fall. Translate `minutes` into an array of 24 elements representing hours, each with the segments in that hour. In order *"to process, in this case, the hour at index 10"*, you just look at index 10 and analyze those time segments. Come back when you have code that attempts that.

Comment: Also, your `minutes` array is structured wrong. You need an array of level/duration pairs. You could use tuples, as you are familiar with them already. The last assignment, `minutes[0] = 781;`, will overwrite the first and that's not what you want.

Comment: @madreflection array initialization fixed. Added existing not working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way. Probably not the most elegant solution, but gets the job done and can be a basis for further optimization. For explanation see comments in the code.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    class percentages {
        public double l0;
        public double l1;
        public double l2;
        public double l3;
        public double l4;
        public double l5;
        
        public string ToString() {
          return $"{l0:F2} {l1:F2} {l2:F2} {l3:F2} {l4:F2} {l5:F2} ";
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var levels = new int[]{0,5,0};
        var minutes = new int[]{658, 1, 781};
        var plist = new percentages[24];
        
        //sum up the minutes to total duration on this day
        //ie minutes will become [658, 659, 1440]
        for (int i = 1; i < minutes.Length; i++) 
            minutes[i] += minutes[i-1];
        
        //lindex is the current index in the levels/minutes array
        var lindex = 0; 
        //pindex is the current index in the percentages array
        var pindex = 0;
        
        var p = new percentages();
        
        //a constant of how much 1 minute contributes in percent of an hour
        var m1 = 100.0 / 60;
        
        //check every minute of the day
        for (int m = 1; m <= 1440; m++) {
            //increment the respective level by 1 minute
            switch(levels[lindex]) {
                case 0: p.l0 += m1; break;
                case 1: p.l1 += m1; break;
                case 2: p.l2 += m1; break;
                case 3: p.l3 += m1; break;
                case 4: p.l4 += m1; break;
                case 5: p.l5 += m1; break;
            }
            
            //if the minutes reached a level change increment the index in the level/minute array
            if (m == minutes[lindex]) lindex++;
            
            //if the minutes reached a full hour, add the current percentages to the list, increment index and reset for the next hour
            if (m % 60 == 0){
                plist[pindex++] = p;
                
                Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
                p = new percentages();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Be aware, there are no sanity checks whatsoever. This will break if `levels` and `minutes` don't have the same length or if the sum of `minutes` is not `1440`. For further use, you should add these checks.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create another array `level_at_min` where the index is a minute in the day.
`level_at_min` will be of size 1440 (I show an algorithm to do it later).

In your example you will have

```
level_at_min[0] = 0 
...
level_at_min[657] = 0 
level_at_min[658] = 5 
level_at_min[659] = 0 
...
level_at_min[1439] = 0
```

If you have that array, you can create an array of lists (of length 60) `levels_at_hour`,
that will give for your example

```
levels_at_hour[0] = [0,0, ..., 0]    
levels_at_hour[1] = [0,0, ..., 0]    
....
levels_at_hour[11] = [0,..., 5,0]    
...
levels_at_hour[23] = [0,0,...,0]
```

With this you can compute the average protection level at each hour, or the percentage of each protection level at each hour, whatever you want.

Algorithm to create `level_at_min`: (`n` the length of array `level`s and array `minutes`)

```
minute_counter = 0
for each block in 0 to n-1
  for each minute in minute_counter to (minute_counter+minutes[block])
    level_at_min[min] = levels[block]
  minute_counter = minute_counter + minutes[block]
```

Algorithm to create `levels_at_hour`:

```
for each hour in 0 to 23:
  for each minute in i*60 to (i+1)*60  
    add level_at_min[minute] to the list levels_at_hour[hour]
```

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow. Thanks in advance.